# Bitbucket webhook to AWS codeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, webhooks, aws-codebuild

Recently AWS codebuild webhook supports PULL_REQUEST_MERGED event,which triggers the build every time a pull request is merged.

However we have to enable the merged event in Bitbucket webhook setting if we create a webhook filter group that uses the PULL_REQUEST_MERGED event type.

I am confused what should be the server URL of the AWS code build.

I read many tutorial but most of them are for integration of bitbucket with jenkins, not sure how to configure with AWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for using AWS CodeBuild. For Bitbucket webhook integration, you can check out this [CodeBuild Bitbucket webhook sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-bitbucket-pull-request.html) in CodeBuild user guide.

Basically when you create a bitbucket webhook through [CodeBuild console](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) or calling CodeBuild's [CreateWebhook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_CreateWebhook.html) API, CodeBuild will create the webhook and fill in the URL for you. You can also configure filter groups with PULL_REQUEST_MERGED event type on CodeBuild console.

After the webhook is created, you can check its settings on Bitbucket site. And you can edit which events will trigger Bitbucket to deliver a webhook payload.